# echoing a functional in php

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to echo a functional button in php.

```
echo "<button type='button' onclick="alert('Hello world!')" >Buy</button>";
```

All it is supposed to do is the user presses it and displays "hello world".

Comment: Do you see how Stack Overflow's syntax highlighting reveals the problem? A good text editor or IDE will do the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to this. Currently you have double speech marks within the code you want echoed. This means it is being mistaken for the end of the echo statement in the middle. Putting backslashes in front of these escapes them so that they are are not interpreted as being part of the PHP syntax.

```
echo "<button type='button' onclick='alert(\"Hello world!\")' >Buy</button>";
```

Comment: Updated with explanation.